# Generic parameter type in Dart?

Tags: dart, generics

I'm trying to create a class that use a generic type as a parameter in a callback that returns some subtype of Flutter's Widget. Here's what I started with:

```
    class Subscriber<P extends PublishingController> extends StatefulWidget {
      const Subscriber({required this.builder, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      final Widget Function(P) builder;

      @override
      _SubscriberState<P> createState() => _SubscriberState<P>();
    }

    class _SubscriberState<P extends PublishingController> extends State<Subscriber> {
      final P publisher = GetIt.instance.get<P>();

      @override
      void initState() {
        publisher.subscribe(rebuild);
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return widget.builder(publisher);
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        publisher.unsubscribe(rebuild);
        super.dispose();
      }

      void rebuild() {
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
```

... with the Publisher:

```
    mixin Publisher {
      List<Function> subscribers = <void Function()>[];

      void subscribe(Function f) {
          subscribers.add(f);
      }

      void unsubscribe(Function f) {
        subscribers.remove(f);
      }

      void publish() {
        for (var f in subscribers) {
          f();
        }
      }
    }

    class PublishingController with Publisher {}
```

... and how I called it:

```
  child: Subscriber<MapController>(
             builder: (controller) => Column(...
```

... with:

```
  class MapController extends PublishingController {...
```

... but that gives me the error:

```
  ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
  The following _TypeError was thrown building Subscriber<MapController>(dirty, state: _SubscriberState<MapController>#d7e05):
  type '(MapController) => Column' is not a subtype of type '(PublishingController) => Widget'
```

I think I'm specifying the parameter type through the generics, and a function can return a subtype of its return type— what am I getting wrong here?

**EDIT**:

I got it working, but I'm not putting this in as an answer— I don't understand what the problem was, or why this version works; I changed my Subscriber class to:

```
    abstract class Builder<P extends PublishingController> extends StatefulWidget {
      const Builder({required this.builder, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      final Widget Function(P) builder;
    }

    class Subscriber<P extends PublishingController> extends Builder<P> {
      const Subscriber({required builder, Key? key}) : super(builder: builder, key: key);

      @override
      _SubscriberState<P> createState() => _SubscriberState<P>();
    }
```

Can someone explain why this change would make the difference?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?  You've shown the `StatefulWidget`, but you haven't shown the corresponding `State` class nor your `createState` method.  I suspect you've probably omitted the generic type argument (e.g. if your `createState` method returns a `_SubscriberState` instead of a `_SubscriberState<P>`), in which case the omission would resort to using `PublishingController` instead of the type originally supplied.

Comment: Does it work if you change `final Widget Function(P) builder;` to `final Widget Function(PublishingController) builder;`?

Comment: @jamesdlin — I edited the code in the question to include some more context.

Comment: @mmcdon20 — I tried making that parameter type a PublishingController, but it didn't help.

Comment: Try declaring `createState` to return a `_SubscriberState<P>`.

Comment: @Crag What happened when you tried changing the parameter type to `PublishingController`? I just tried it myself and the error message appears to go away. I am not sure what you tried, but I am suggesting to change the type of `builder` and leave everything else exactly the same as it is.

Comment: @jamesdlin — changing the createState return type didn't fix it ("_SubscriberState<P> createState() => _SubscriberState<P>();")

Comment: @mmcdon20 — specifying the parameter as a PublishingController makes it fail at compile time with errors from the View like "Error: The getter 'circleCenter' isn't defined for the class 'PublishingController'."; the View needs a MapController.

Comment: I think the reason it's not working may be that function types have contravariant parameter types, and Dart is erasing the type I'm passing in; I suspect I have my syntax wrong somehow with the generic type or the function definition.

Comment: @Craig, I'm not quite sure then if it's possible to achieve that with darts current generics implementation. According to the language tour, dart generics are reified and not erased (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generic-collections-and-the-types-they-contain). And, according to this issue, "every type variable declared for a generic class is considered covariant" https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/524.

Comment: @mmcdon20, I believe it can be done; I was trying to make a simpler version of the getx package, which basically does this, and I've been looking at their code to try to figure out what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_SubscriberState<P>` class extends `State<Subscriber>`, which in your case is shorthand for `State<Subscriber<PublishingController>>`, *not* for `State<Subscriber<P>>`.

The static type of the `_SubscriberState<P>`'s inherited `widget` member therefore will be `Subscriber<PublishingController>`, and the static type of `widget.builder` will be `Widget Function(PublishingController)`.  At runtime, the associated `Subscriber` object has a reference to a `Column Function(MapController)` object.  However, that cannot be treated as a `Widget Function(PublishingController)` since it does not accept all `PublishingController` arguments, so you end up with a runtime error.

See: [Why am I getting TypeError at runtime with my generic StatefulWidget class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71897026/)

Comment: I had previously written a longer answer, but I've moved it to what I hope to be a more canonical question. (I had originally intended to make *this* question a canonical question but decided against it.)