# Why am I getting TypeError at runtime with my generic StatefulWidget class?

Tags: flutter, generics

I have a generic `StatefulWidget` class that has a `Function` callback.  When I try to invoke that callback, I get a runtime `TypeError`:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building MyStatefulWidget<int>(dirty, state:
MyState<int>#cacb3):
type '(int) => Widget' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => Widget'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MyStatefulWidget<int>
  MyStatefulWidget:file:///path/to/my_flutter_project/lib/main.dart:11:13

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      MyState.build (package:my_flutter_project/main.dart:33:19)
```

Reproducible example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

Widget f(int n) => Text('$n');

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyStatefulWidget<int>(callback: foo, value: 42),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget Function(T) callback;
  final T value;

  const MyStatefulWidget({
    required this.callback,
    required this.value,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyState<T> createState() => MyState<T>();
}

class MyState<T> extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.callback(widget.value);
  }
}
```

I've tried explicitly constructing `MyStatefulWidget` as `MyStatefulWidget<int>`, but that doesn't help.  Where is the `Widget Function(dynamic)` type coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MyState createState() => MyState();` omits the type arguments, so it returns a `MyState`, which is shorthand for `MyState<dynamic>`.

Additionally, `MyState<T> extends State<MyStatefulWidget>` is shorthand for `... extends State<MyStatefulWidget<dynamic>>`, *not* for `... extends State<MyStatefulWidget<T>>` as intended.

The static type of the `MyState<T>`'s inherited `widget` member therefore will be `MyStatefulWidget<dynamic>`, and the static type of `widget.callback` will be `Widget Function(dynamic)`.  At runtime, the associated `MyStatefulWidget` object has a reference to `f` (a `Widget Function(int)`.  However, that cannot be treated as `Widget Function(dynamic)` (as expected by `MyState<T>`) since `f` cannot accept all `dynamic` arguments, so you end up with a `TypeError` at runtime.

### Bottom line

If you have a generic `StatefulWidget`, you must explicitly and consistently supply the type parameters everywhere that the `StatefulWidget` refers to its `State` class or where the `State` refers to its `StatefulWidget` class.  Common mistakes are:

- Neglecting type parameters in `createState`.
- Neglecting type parameters when declaring inheritance for the corresponding `State` class.

So:

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
  MyState createState() => MyState(); // WRONG
}

class MyState<T> extends State<MyStatefulWidget> { // WRONG
  ...
}
```

instead should be:

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
  MyState<T> createState() => MyState<T>();
}

class MyState<T> extends State<MyStatefulWidget<T>>
  ...
}
```

The [`strict_raw_types` analysis option](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks) sometimes can help catch such mistakes, although the current implementation seems to check only for implicitly `dynamic` type parameters and doesn't seem to catch cases where the type parameter is restricted (such as if you have `MyStatefulWidget<T extends num>`).

Comment: Thank you amigo! my issue was with State<MyStatefulWidget<T>>