Flutter builder function with generics
I have a builder function with generics and when I use it I get an error
type '(BuildContext, AppResources?, Widget?) => Widget' is not a subtype of type '((BuildContext, Object?, Widget?) => Widget)?'

Obviously AppResources? is a subtype of Object? so the whole method signature (BuildContext, AppResources?, Widget?) => Widget should be a subtype of (BuildContext, Object?, Widget?) => Widget or shouldn't?
I tried with no-generics builder (SimpleBuilder), it works fine. How can I use generics builder (GenericsBuilder<GEN>)?
typedef SimpleBuilder = Widget Function(BuildContext context, Object? object, Widget? child);
typedef GenericsBuilder<GEN extends Object> = Widget Function(BuildContext context, GEN? object, Widget? child);

class AppLocalization<RES extends Object> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget? child;
  final SimpleBuilder? builder;
  //final GenericsBuilder<RES>? builder;
  final Locale? defaultLocale;

  const AppLocalization({this.child, this.builder, this.defaultLocale, super.key})
      : assert(builder != null || child != null);

  @override
  AppLocalizationState createState() => AppLocalizationState<RES>();
}

class AppLocalizationState<RES extends Object> extends State<AppLocalization> {
  RES? _resources;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _resources = AppResources(); // initalized different way in real app
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder?.call(context, _resources, widget.child) ?? widget.child!;
  }
}

later I use it in build method of some other widget
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AppLocalization<AppResources>(
    builder: (context, res, child) => res == null
        ? const SizedBox.shrink()
        : const Text('hurray')
    );
}


"so the whole method signature (BuildContext, AppResources?, Widget?) => Widget should be a subtype of (BuildContext, Object?, Widget?) => Widget or shouldn't?" No. A callback function that accepts only an AppResources? argument cannot be used as a function that can accept any Object?.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61966636/

You don't show enough of AppLocalizationState for me to tell exactly what you're doing.  Possibly you're falling into this trap: Why am I getting TypeError at runtime with my generic StatefulWidget class?

But the method signature in typedef isn't (BuildContext, Object?, Widget?) => Widget but (BuildContext, GEN?, Widget?) => Widget and when GEN is AppResources (via RES generics in AppLocalization<RES> then both signatures should match. That's what I don't understand.

Thanks for pointing to https://stackoverflow.com/a/71897027/1444083, the missing piece of code was generics  in extends State in class AppLocalizationState<RES extends Object> extends State<AppLocalization<RES>>.
